# When using VirtualBox with qcow2, how to set the size of qcow2 to a fixed size?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

When using VirtualBox with .vmdk, it is possible via VirtualBox GUI to set to "fixed size" if desired. When using VirtualBox and .qcow2, the menu item "fixed size" is grayed out.

If you do not set the configuration of e.g. .vmdk or .qcow2 to "fixed size" via GUI in VirtualBox, said files may grow in size when used, so that in such a case, if necessary, they have to be reduced in size by appropriate measures (but this is not the subject of this question).

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as a “fixed-size” QCOW2 image. QCOW2 is a dynamically-growing image format. If you do not want to use a dynamically-growing image format, you have to use a different format.

The only format VirtualBox offers 100% support for is its own, VDI.

Comment: .vmdk format are offering fixed-size also, but don't offer deduplication.